# How to disable tree list rows to be selected in devexpress

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, treelist

I have created a tree list for showing the sector and blocks of memory, now I need to disable the selection of root node and also need to disable the rows of blocks which are already occupied, so that only enable rows can be selected from the tree list.

Also the disabled rows text are little bit lighter for the user to differentiate.

Here I am attaching a sample image for the reference, what I need to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [TreeList.ShowingEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_ShowingEditortopic) event?
Something like this:

```
void mytreelist_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {  
   if(mytreelist.FocusedNode.Level == 0 /* root */ || SomeOtherCriteria()) 
   {
      e.Cancel = true;  
   }  
 }
```

You can handle [TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCell](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCell) to make a row appear disabled:

```
private void mytreelist_CustomDrawNodeCell(object sender, CustomDrawNodeCellEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Node.Level == 0 /* root */ || SomeOtherCriteria()) 
    {
      e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }  
}
```

Comment: ShowingEditor event wont invoked as my treeview control is not editable to the user

Comment: Set Editable and ReadOnly to true.